# passing command line argument value to a string

Tags: command, line

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    string str = atoi[1];
    cout<< str;
}
```

I get an error in this, is there any solution, so that when I get input from the command line argument and store that in str, and use for the operation

Comment: Whats `atoi[1]`?

Comment: `string str = atoi(argv[1])`....